# Get the data posted to URL in laravel

Tags: guzzle

I'm using an API, for which i'm passing callback url. To this callback url data will be posted from api.

How can I get this data from callback url.

This is my code.

In response data is not there.

```
public function getData(Request $request){
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $response = $client->request('POST', 'api?callbackurl=url/getData'
            ]
        ]);
  }
```

Comment: Does that compile ?

Comment: Just use a return statement,

Comment: returning response is not showing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You callback URL is just another Laravel action. Create an action for `url/getData` (but you probably should to full URL instead) and wait for the data there.